# Orange tabby has black around his eyelids

Tags: cats, grooming

My 4yr old tabby Lex has these black spots that line his eyelids. He's had them for at least a couple months (since I've noticed), seems otherwise fine and doesn't mind me looking at his eyes. I haven't tried to scrape it off as I don't want to go poking around in his eye. I'm not sure if it's irremovable pigment or gunk. Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Do you have a picture of the spots on the cat?

Comment: Orange cats often have freckles.

Answer (score 3):

Seconding Oldcat's comment: Freckles, almost certainly. My two orange tabbies both have similar spots where one can see bare skin. Normal skin coloration. Leave it alone.

If you're still nervous, ask the vet next time he's in for a checkup.

(And yes, I was startled too when I first saw this. Vet said that was a common reaction.)